# How to display text when RSS feed is empty

Tags: javascript, php, html, rss

I have been struggling with this for a while now, I got some help from a similar question but I can't seem to make it work in my example.

I have an RSS feed on my website and what I am trying to do is display a message saying "No Warnings" when the RSS feed is blank/empty.  If there is something in the RSS feed then I just want to show that.

For the life of me I can't get this to work! I can't get it to recognize the feed is blank...is this possible??

Here is my code,

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en" dir="ltr" lang="en">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
<title>Loading directly an RSS feed and displaying it</title></head>
<link type="text/css" href="rss-style.css" rel="stylesheet">

<body bgcolor="#FFE991">
<div id="zone" ><img src="/images/alert-icon-120.png" alt="Weather Warnings for SA. Issued by the Australian Bureau of Meteorology" align="left" style="padding-right: 4pt"width="15" height="15" border="0"/>&nbsp;Current South Australian Statewide Warnings:<small><em><font color="black"> &nbsp;&nbsp;Provided by The Bureau of Meteorology</font></em></small>
</div>
<fieldset class="rsslibbomsa">
<?php
    require_once("rsslib.php");
    $url = "http://www.bom.gov.au/fwo/IDZ00057.warnings_sa.xml";
    $rss = RSS_Display($url, 15, false, false);

if ($rss == '')
{  
              // nothing shown, do whatever you want
    echo 'No Current Warnings';
    }


  else
{
// something to display

echo $rss123;

}

?>
</fieldset>
</body>
</html>
```

If it helps RSS_Display is from the rsslib.php file, which I have provided below,

```
<?php
/*
    RSS Extractor and Displayer
    (c) 2007-2010  Scriptol.com - Licence Mozilla 1.1.
    rsslib.php

    Requirements:
    - PHP 5.
    - A RSS feed.

    Using the library:
    Insert this code into the page that displays the RSS feed:

    <?php
    require_once("rsslib.php");
    echo RSS_Display("http://www.bom.gov.au/fwo/IDZ00059.warnings_vic.xml", 15);
    ? >

*/

$RSS_Content = array();

function RSS_Tags($item, $type)
{
        $y = array();
        $tnl = $item->getElementsByTagName("title");
        $tnl = $tnl->item(0);
        $title = $tnl->firstChild->textContent;

        $tnl = $item->getElementsByTagName("link");
        $tnl = $tnl->item(0);
        $link = $tnl->firstChild->textContent;

        $tnl = $item->getElementsByTagName("pubDate");
        $tnl = $tnl->item(0);
        $date = $tnl->firstChild->textContent;      

        $tnl = $item->getElementsByTagName("description");
        $tnl = $tnl->item(0);
        $description = $tnl->firstChild->textContent;

        $y["title"] = $title;
        $y["link"] = $link;
        $y["date"] = $date;     
        $y["description"] = $description;
        $y["type"] = $type;

        return $y;
}


function RSS_Channel($channel)
{
    global $RSS_Content;

    $items = $channel->getElementsByTagName("item");

    // Processing channel

    $y = RSS_Tags($channel, 0);     // get description of channel, type 0
    array_push($RSS_Content, $y);

    // Processing articles

    foreach($items as $item)
    {
        $y = RSS_Tags($item, 1);    // get description of article, type 1
        array_push($RSS_Content, $y);
    }
}

function RSS_Retrieve($url)
{
    global $RSS_Content;

    $doc  = new DOMDocument();
    $doc->load($url);

    $channels = $doc->getElementsByTagName("channel");

    $RSS_Content = array();

    foreach($channels as $channel)
    {
         RSS_Channel($channel);
    }

}


function RSS_RetrieveLinks($url)
{
    global $RSS_Content;

    $doc  = new DOMDocument();
    $doc->load($url);

    $channels = $doc->getElementsByTagName("channel");

    $RSS_Content = array();

    foreach($channels as $channel)
    {
        $items = $channel->getElementsByTagName("item");
        foreach($items as $item)
        {
            $y = RSS_Tags($item, 1);    // get description of article, type 1
            array_push($RSS_Content, $y);
        }

    }

}


function RSS_Links($url, $size = 15)
{
    global $RSS_Content;

    $page = "<ul>";

    RSS_RetrieveLinks($url);
    if($size > 0)
        $recents = array_slice($RSS_Content, 0, $size + 1);

    foreach($recents as $article)
    {
        $type = $article["type"];
        if($type == 0) continue;
        $title = $article["title"];
        $link = $article["link"];
        $page .= "<li><a href=\"$link\">$title</a></li>\n";         
    }

    $page .="</ul>/n";

    return $page;

}



function RSS_Display($url, $size = 15, $site = 0, $withdate = 0)
{
    global $RSS_Content;

    $opened = false;
    $page = "";
    $site = (intval($site) == 0) ? 1 : 0;

    RSS_Retrieve($url);
    if($size > 0)
        $recents = array_slice($RSS_Content, $site, $size + 1 - $site);

    foreach($recents as $article)
    {
        $type = $article["type"];
        if($type == 0)
        {
            if($opened == true)
            {
                $page .="</ul>\n";
                $opened = false;
            }
            $page .="<b>";
        }
        else
        {
            if($opened == false) 
            {
                $page .= "<ul>\n";
                $opened = true;
            }
        }
        $title = $article["title"];
        $link = $article["link"];
        $page .= "<li><a href=\"$link\">$title</a>";
        if($withdate)
        {
      $date = $article["date"];
      $page .=' <span class="rssdate">'.$date.'</span>';
    }
        $description = $article["description"];
        if($description != false)
        {
            $page .= "<br><span class='rssdesc'>$description</span>";
        }
        $page .= "</li>\n";         

        if($type==0)
        {
            $page .="</b><br />";
        }

    }

    if($opened == true)
    {   
        $page .="</ul>\n";
    }
    return $page."\n";

}


?>
```

Any help would be much appreciated.

Many thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you look at the rsslib code, you see that if the rss has no articles, the returned string will be `\n`.

The test to check if the RSS is empty should be `if ($rss == "\n")`

---

In addition to this, rsslib seems to be an old code (2010) and it is not object oriented (this is a problem because there are global vars defined outside the functions which can be in conflict with your code.

Moreover, this class does all the formatting of the RSS so if you want to change it, you will need to change the rsslib code.

You should consider using an other class like this one : https://github.com/dg/rss-php which is object oriented and easy to use.

Comment: That worked!  Thanks, much appreciated.  I will also look into your other suggestion....thanks again.